# Signed Package, Am I ready now?

Tags: android

after doing **right-click on package -> Export signed application package... -> verify with valid keystore** i got an `APK`.

To get sure i used `jarsigner` to check if my app is correctly signed.

```
$ jarsigner -verify -verbose -certs my_application.apk
```

and i got `jar verified` as response.

Is my APK now correctly signed with a release key? Ready to upload?

Also how can i check, like it is recommended by the android documentation, my signed apk on my phone? (To check  if proguard didn't cut of something which is necessary for my app and so on..)

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: it´s just simple....You are ready....and You just need to delete Your app from Your phone which is installed by the ide and copy the apk onto it. Then install it like You install every other app from playstore....

Comment: Downvote without comment. An envious guy is online ! ;)

Comment: Yeah, I also hate that......but that´s how it is here....many poeple voting down without a comment...

Answer (score 0):

If your APK is not signed correctly, you will not be able to upload it to the Play-Store.